# How to stop fluid going straight through a .stl imported obstacle?

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision

After looking for answers, I have set the resolution up to 100, changed the obstacle initialization to shell and added a Solidify modifier to the obstacle. See below

[image: fluid obstacle]

Comment: What is the fluid type of your pipe? You need to set it to "Obstacle" if you want the simulation to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your pipe object, you just need to apply location, rotation and scale and it will work. Press Ctrl+A, choose location, repeat shortcuts to choose rotation and scale.